# Can I make a variable that holds a point in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In Metafont and Metapost I can easily make a variable `z1` (as long as it is the letter z followed by an index number) represent a point like this:

`z1=(1,2);`

and I can use this to make a line, like in:

`draw z1--(7,5);`

Can I make the same thing in Tikz ? I cannot find it anywhere, and if i write a code like:

`\z1=(1,2);`
`\draw z1--(7,5);`

It gives me an error, and it would make my work a lot easier if I could reference one point to one single variable that I could change once and it would affect every instance in wich this variable is used.

Comment: I don't think this is properly tagged as only concerns TikZ.

Comment: This is called a `node`. You can make a node without any content by writing `\coordinate (z1) at (1,2);` then draw like this `\draw (z1) -- (7,5);`.

Comment: @SebGlav I wouldn't call a coordinate *a node without a content*. A node defines more than a single coordinate. What the OP is looking for isn't a node, for sure.

Comment: Note also that named coordinates are stored globally.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Globally, but only for the current `tikzpicture` environment; unless one uses `remember picture` for the defining environment and another `remember picture` for the picture where they want to access the coordinate again.

Comment: @PhilippImhof - Actually, the coordinates/nodes are saved as 5 separate global macros (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570640/can-tikz-matrices-be-forgotten/570765?r=SearchResults&s=1|12.1469#570765).  Remember picture mostly saves the origin location to the aux file using \pdfsavepos in order to find it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (z1) at (1,2);
   \draw (z1) -- (7,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Addendum to Philipp's answer: You don't have to define the names of coordinates separately, but can do it on the fly whenever you want to refer to the point later on, by adding `coordinate (name)` after the place where the point has been reached. In your example:

```
\draw (1,2) coordinate (z1) -- ++(6,3) coordinate (z2);
```

From now on, in the remaining picture, you can refer to `(1,2)` as `(z1)` and to `(7,5)` as `(z2)`. In this example, `(z2)` is defined relative to `(z1)` by adding the difference `(6,3)`.

Whether coordinates should be defined separately or inline, is a matter of taste and of the role they play. If `(z1)` belongs to the given information (the information defining the layout), then an explicit definition is probably better. If `(z1)` is rather an auxiliary point depending on the construction, then an inline definition is more natural.