# Reuse of coordinate names in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, coordinates

Many times I reuse help coordinate names in `tikz` pictures.
Normally, they are overwritten.
Now I have found an instance where they are maintained.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Reuse of coordinate names overwrites them:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
    \node (A) at (\x,0){.};
  \draw[red] (A) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

When placed in a macro also:

\def\overwritecoords{%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
    \node (A) at (\x,0){.};}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \overwritecoords
  \draw[green] (A) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

But when the \verb|\foreach| uses a macro, not:

\def\placecoord{\node (A) at (\x,0){.};}
\def\keepcoords{%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
    \placecoord}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \keepcoords
  \draw[blue] (A) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}


Although, they can only be used once:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \keepcoords
  \draw[blue] (A) circle(2pt);
  \draw[->] (A)--++(0,-1); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \keepcoords
  \draw[->] (A)--++(0,-1); 
  \draw[blue] (A) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

If the same name is reused again, the previous ones are lost, as usual:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \keepcoords
  \node (A) at (6,0){.};
  \draw[orange] (A) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I could not find a description of this behaviour but, since the manual is so extensive, I might have overlooked it.
I do not understand why and how should `tikz` maintain a list of coordinates with the same name, when normally they are overwritten.
I am a bit worried that at some point, in such a set-up, `tikz` might pick the wrong help coordinate, or more than one, for drawing my picture.
Could that happen?
Is there a way to avoid the accumulation of coordinates with the same name?

On the other hand, if I use this behaviour for some purpose, would that be stable in new updates of the package?

[image]

Comment: The `\draw` command in your `\keepcoords` is being drawn in to the `\foreach` loop.  I don't know enough about how `\foreach` should be delimited to know _why_ this is happening, but placing a semi-colon after `\placecoord` in `\keepcoords` stops this, as does writing `\keepcoords;`.

Comment: I did a bit more digging ...

Comment: Consider also that coordinate names are global in Ti*k*Z --- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459492/local-scoped-coordinate-names-in-tikz

Comment: @Rmano Yes, I am aware that the node names are global. The thing is that, since they are a TeX macro in the end, \pgf@sh@ns@<name>, how can there be more than one. Especially when they are global

Comment: Somewhat related; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570640/can-tikz-matrices-be-forgotten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PGF manual explains how `\foreach` figures out the body of its loop in Section 88 "Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement":

> Syntax for the commands. Let us move on to a more complicated setting. The first complication
> occurs when the  are not some text in curly braces. If the `\foreach` statement does not
> encounter an opening brace, it will instead **scan everything up to the next semicolon** and use this as
> .

(bold-emphasis mine)

A key part of this is that the scan does not expand as it goes.  So the semi-colon inside `\placecoord` is not seen and the `\foreach` takes everything up to the semi-colon at the end of the `\draw` command.  Thus the `\draw` is dragged into the `\foreach` loop.

To block this behaviour (assuming that this is what you want to do) then you need to ensure that TikZ/PGF encounters the semi-colon at the right place without expansion.

One option is to put it in after `\keepcoords`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \keepcoords;
  \draw[blue] (A) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Another is to put it inside `\keepcoords`:

```
\def\keepcoords{%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
    \placecoord;}
```

Yet another is to use braces to delimit the body of the loop.

```
\def\keepcoords{%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
  {\placecoord}}
```

As for your question about *relying* on this behaviour, I would say "It's documented, so it's likely to stay.".  But from how you write about it then I'm not sure it's behaving how you think it is behaving - in particular, TikZ/PGF is *not* maintaining a list of nodes defined with the same label, each overwrites the previous one, but rather the `\draw` is being used as each one is defined.  So *if* this is what you want, then you can rely on it (as much as anything).

Comment: Thank you for showing how to overwrite the previous names, which is what I was intending to do. I will definitely do it like that to avoid problems. But how is it even possible that the names are maintained, especially when there is not a list of node names. As far as I am aware, the names are ultimately a TeX macro \pgf@sh@ns@<name>. How can there be more than one?

Comment: The names _aren't_ maintained.  It is that the `\draw` command is executed just after each node is defined and before it is overwritten with the next one.

Comment: But the `\draw` is way after naming the nodes. The second one, I mean the one with the circles

Comment: It is inside the iteration? Ok, that makes sense.

Comment: The `\keepcoords` does not finish with a semicolon, so it is the semicolon of  the `\draw` which does it and is used every iteration. Therefore, all the coordinates are drawn with a circle